# Microsoft Pinyin IME switches to English mode automatically - Windows OS

Tags: ime

Why does Windows Microsoft Pinyin IME changes to english mode from chinese mode automatically? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4):

Windows applications can programmatically choose the input language and IME mode for themselves, which is why the Pinyin input method is automatically switched to English or English mode. As far as I know, this behavior cannot be blocked.

Comment: Recently, I found when I am clicking the textbox, the IME automatically crazy switching. My app is. NET5 (NET CORE). But the same code in .NET 4.x is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Pinyin IME has (by default) the `Shift` key mapped as a shortcut key for switching between Chinese and English entry mode. So when typing, if you hit the `Shift` key by accident it may seem that it just switched by itself.

Not sure how to programmatically stop this from happening, but if you simply want to have it stop bothering you can change the Pinyin IME options （the following steps based on Windows 10, but other versions probably similar):

- Open `Language Preferences` (via the pop-up menu when you left-mouse click on the IME language notification area icon)
- See the section with the `Languages`, find the Chinese language and click on it to select it
- Click on the `Options` button and scroll down the dialog to the `Keyboards`. Click on the `Microsoft Pinyin` input method to select it and click on `Options`
- Under `Mode switching` find the `Choose the key you use to switch between Chinese and English` option. From the drop-down list, choose `None` and then you won't accidentally switch the mode via the keyboard anymore (you can still change it by clicking on the Pinyin IME notification icon to switch between Chinese/English mode).